# Changing multiple directory permissions at once

Tags: permissions

Is there a way to make every current user home directory (/home/username) have read permission for 'Other'? I am attempting to monitor the .bash_history directory but each user's home directory only gives access to the owner. I would like to grant group and/or other Read permission. Ubuntu 14.04 terminal is what I am using.

Comment: Ubuntu by default already grants read permissions for group and other.

Answer (score 0):

Try `chmod g+r /home -R`

That should change the permissions for every file under /home to have read access for group. The -R option runs the command recursively